How to add custom view on particular page for detail page in Nova laravel
I am using Nova laravel. I have a requirement where in index page I am showing list view where in table on field have IDs of other table. Now in detail page I want to show the listing instead of current default page. I want to show a table view same as index page on detail page. Is there a way to do so? I tried using tools but I can I replicate view on detail page?
